# Checkbox behaving as radiobox

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery: make checkboxes act like radio buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697941/jquery-make-checkboxes-act-like-radio-buttons)

Hey All,

Im looking to make some checkboxes act like radio buttons.

For example, i have the following code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="xhtml" value="B" />
<input type="checkbox" name="xhtml" value="I" />
<input type="checkbox" name="xhtml" value="A" />
```

The problem is that i can select all three of them, i only want to be able to select one out of the 3.

I know its easier to change to radio buttons, but i have to use checkboxes for this project.

Cheers,

Comment: For my own understanding of the madness, can you explain why you "have to use checkboxes for this project"?

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery. See: http://blog.schuager.com/2008/09/mutually-exclusive-checkboxes-with.html