# How to hide/show or switch in between two div-form fields using check box?

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am presently working on a form and I would like to show/hide div-form field using check box. In my research I came across;

show/hide input-form field using radio button here:
https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/LEGXOK

Please I would like to apply check box instead of radio-buttin to show/hide div-form fields and not input.

Example:
I want to create a from filed where an applicant can either upload their cv/resume
using the check-box

Upload form script:

```
<div class="element-file" title="Click here to Upload Resume"><label class="title"></label><div class="item-cont"><label class="large"><div class="button">UPLOAD</div><div class="file_text">NO UPLOAD DETECTED</div><span class="icon-place"></span></label></div></div>
```

OR

Manual Entry:

```
<div class="element-input" title="Enter your Full Name as indicated here."><label class="title"><span class="required">Required</span></label><div class="item-cont"><span class="icon-place"></span></div></div>
```

I want to use check-box to switch in between this two Div-form fields Using the behaviour from this sample:
https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/LEGXOK

Thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: It should be identical.  Go to the codepen, and change the input type from "radio" to "checkbox" and you'll see it works.  However, since you are looking at an either-or case, it seems a radio would be more appropriate than a check box.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [making checkboxes behave like radio buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23523987/making-checkboxes-behave-like-radio-buttons)

Comment: That will work but not like radio buttons.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23523987/making-checkboxes-behave-like-radio-buttons for how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Just add this code to your bindUIActions method. It will toggle the checkboxes.

```
  bindUIActions: function() {
    $("input[type='radio'], input[type='checkbox']").on("change", this.applyConditionalRequired, function() {
      if (this.id == 'choice-animals-dogs') {
        var checked = ($('#choice-animals-cats').checked) ? true : false;
        $('#choice-animals-cats').prop('checked', checked);
      }
      if (this.id == 'choice-animals-cats') {
        var checked = ($('#choice-animals-dogs').checked) ? true : false;
        $('#choice-animals-dogs').prop('checked', checked);
      }
    });
  },
```