# Create Checkbox (or checkboxlist) from a list using foreach

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, checkbox, checkboxlist

I am trying to make a checkbox or checkboxlist from a list. i tried:

```
@foreach (var bundle in Model.BundleList)
{

    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="labels" value="@bundle.BundleType" id="@bundle.BundleType" />
        <label for="@bundle.BundleType">@bundle.BundleType</label>
    </div>
}
```

but how can i know which checkbox is selected? i also want to have radiobutton behaviour, which mean only one checkbox can be selected.

Comment: Why do you need checkboxes if you are going to uses them like radio buttons?

Comment: If you want radio button behavior, then use radio buttons (not checkboxes)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697941/jquery-make-checkboxes-act-like-radio-buttons

Comment: @Kimos, add a class to all checkboxes and find checked checkboxes by `$('.class_name:checked')`

Comment: Hi, i made some changes and i added a jquery script to make the radiobutton behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JQuery you can get selected checkbox by `$('input:checkbox:checked')` selector.

And you can have radiobutton behaviour of checkbox like following.

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function () {
    if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).prop('checked', true);
        return;
    }
    $("input:checkbox").not(this).removeAttr("checked");
});
```

**Update:** To set selected checkbox value in a hidden field.

Html

`<input id="SelectedProducts" name="SelectedProducts" type="hidden" />`

Jquery

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function () {
    if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).prop('checked', true);
        return;
    }

    var checkvalue = $(this).val();
    $('#SelectedProducts').val(checkvalue);

    $("input:checkbox").not(this).removeAttr("checked");
});
```

Comment: i cant get the selected checkbox value and put it in a hidden property
i tried:  
var checkvalue = $('input[name=labels]:checked').map(function () {
        return this.value;
    }).get();

i dont know if the checkvalue is correct. how can i assign checkvalue to a propperty in the model?

Comment: What do mean by hidden property? Did you mean hidden input?

Comment: yes hidden input    @this.Hidden(m => m.SelectedProducts)

Comment: after checking one of the checkbox and see in F12 (developertool) then SelectedProducts value is empty