# How to uncheck previously checked checkbox?

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I have 5 checkboxes and only one is allowed. Lets say user clicks on check box one, but if he clicks on checkbox two, checkbox one has to be unchecked. How can I achieve this?

HTML

```
 <div class="form-group form-group-custom" id="checkboxes">
        <?php
        foreach ( $education_levels_array as $key => $employee ) {
            echo '
            <div class="checkbox checkbox-inline">
                <input class="educationCheckboxes" type="checkbox" name="userEducationDegree[]" id=0' . $employee['education_id'] . ' value="' . $employee['education_id'] . '" />
                <label for=0' . $employee['education_id'] . '>' . $employee['education'] . '</label>

            </div>';

        }
        ?>
    </div>
```

I tried to store it in a variable, but right now it won't let me select any options.

```
var lastChecked;
        $(".educationCheckboxes").on("change", function () {
            console.log(lastChecked);
            if ($(this).prop("checked", true)) {
                lastChecked = $(this);
            }
            lastChecked.prop("checked",false);
        });
```

Comment: This is easy ... ***you use radio buttons***! That's what they are there for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery: make checkboxes act like radio buttons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697941/jquery-make-checkboxes-act-like-radio-buttons)

Comment: store the state of actual checkbox (this) and, before you set true/false, uncheck all checkboxes:   $(".educationCheckboxes").each( funciton () { $(this).prop("checked",false);  });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you're unchecking the current checkbox if it gets checked.
You need to change the order in which you're doing things.

```
var lastChecked = null;
$(".educationCheckboxes").on("change", function () {
    console.log(lastChecked);
    if(lastChecked && lastChecked != $(this)){
        lastChecked.prop("checked", false);
    }
    if ($(this).prop("checked", true)) {
        lastChecked = $(this);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

using `change` event of all checkboxes with class `educationCheckboxes`. First check whether currently selected checkbox is checked or not. If it does, then  uncheck all checkboxes using class selector with class `educationCheckboxes`. This will uncheck all checkboxes including the currently selected checkbox then
again check the current checkbox. That's it

```js
$('.educationCheckboxes').change(function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
    $('.educationCheckboxes').prop('checked',false);
    $(this).prop('checked',true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="educationCheckboxes">
<input type="checkbox" class="educationCheckboxes">
<input type="checkbox" class="educationCheckboxes">
<input type="checkbox" class="educationCheckboxes">
```