# Laravel Radio Button unchecked

Tags: html, laravel

when i'm trying to check an option it the other options suppose to be unchecked automatically but it's not
also i try to uncheck option manually but it doesn't work

**NOTE**

i can't use the same name because each role have his own id i want user just select 1 option

[image: Radio Bottoms checked at the same time]

code

```
<div class="col-12">
                            <div class="custom-control custom-radio mb-5">
                                <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" name="admin" id="example-radio1" value="option1"{{$user->hasRole('Admin') ? 'checked' : ''}}>
                                <label class="custom-control-label" for="example-radio1">Admin</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="custom-control custom-radio mb-5">
                                <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" name="editor" id="example-radio2" value="option1"{{$user->hasRole('Editor') ? 'checked' : ''}}>
                                <label class="custom-control-label" for="example-radio2">Editor</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="custom-control custom-radio mb-5">
                                <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" name="user" id="example-radio3" value="option1"{{$user->hasRole('User') ? 'checked' : ''}}>
                                <label class="custom-control-label" for="example-radio3">User</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: HTML101 Use the same name if you want radio groups: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio

Comment: Those `'checked'` should probably have a space before them

Comment: i can't use the same name because each role have his own id i want user just select 1 option

Comment: What? That's _why_ you use the same name, so they are grouped and the user can only select one of them

Answer (score 1):

as @kerbholz said, radio groups should have the same name. See example below:

```
<div class="col-12">
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio mb-5">
                <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" name="role" id="role-admin" value="admin"{{$user->hasRole('Admin') ? 'checked' : ''}}>
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="role-admin">Admin</label>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio mb-5">
                <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" name="role" id="role-editor" value="editor"{{$user->hasRole('Editor') ? 'checked' : ''}}>
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="role-editor">Editor</label>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio mb-5">
                <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" name="role" id="role-user" value="user"{{$user->hasRole('User') ? 'checked' : ''}}>
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="role-user">User</label>
        </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Now, process the inputs in the controller as you want/need.

Comment: @kerbholz, thanks, i was copy-pasting :D I don't think he will need ID's but, ye, you are right!

Comment: i can't use the same name because each role have his own id i want user just select 1 option

Comment: @HamadEssa, that's the least of your problems. In your controller you can check this...

Answer (score 0):

> Do like that

```
<div class="col-12">
                                <div class="custom-control custom-radio mb-5">
                                    <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" name="check" id="example-radio1" value="option1"{{$user->hasRole('Admin') ? 'checked' : ''}}>
                                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="example-radio1">Admin</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="custom-control custom-radio mb-5">
                                    <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" name="check" id="example-radio2" value="option1"{{$user->hasRole('Editor') ? 'checked' : ''}}>
                                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="example-radio2">Editor</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="custom-control custom-radio mb-5">
                                    <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" name="check" id="example-radio3" value="option1"{{$user->hasRole('User') ? 'checked' : ''}}>
                                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="example-radio3">User</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: you can use class instead of id

Comment: i can't use the same name because each role have his own id i want user just select 1 option

Comment: You can't do that  , please check  this  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_radio.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use the same value of attribute **name** for all the **radio** input fields instead of using different name

```html
<div class="col-12">
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio mb-5">
            <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" name="role_type" id="example-radio1"
                   value="Admin"{{$user->hasRole('Admin') ? 'checked' : ''}}>
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="example-radio1">Admin</label>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio mb-5">
            <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" name="role_type" id="example-radio2"
                   value="Editor"{{$user->hasRole('Editor') ? 'checked' : ''}}>
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="example-radio2">Editor</label>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio mb-5">
            <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" name="role_type" id="example-radio3"
                   value="User"{{$user->hasRole('User') ? 'checked' : ''}}>
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="example-radio3">User</label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: i cant use the same name because each role have his own id 
i want user just select 1 option

Comment: As far as i know that you have to use the same name. The reason is You can't let user to select any one option out of three until you give the same name. If you assign different value of name then more than one radio button can be selected. Hope you understand the fact. To achieve your goal assign the value attribute with Admin, Editor & User respectively. Have a look at my solution i have posted.

Answer (score 0):

To create a radio box it is necessary to use the same name for all radio input fields.
If you don't want to give the same name to your radio boxes then you have another option create custom radio boxes with jquery

```
if($('input[name="admin"]').is(':checked')) {
    $(this).prop('checked',true);
    $('input[name="editor"]').prop('checked',false);
    $('input[name="user"]').prop('checked',false);
} else if($('input[name="editor"]').is(':checked')) {
    $(this).prop('checked',true);
    $('input[name="admin"]').prop('checked',false);
    $('input[name="user"]').prop('checked',false);
} else if($('input[name="user"]').is(':checked')) {
    $(this).prop('checked',true);
    $('input[name="admin"]').prop('checked',false);
    $('input[name="editor"]').prop('checked',false);
}
```

Hope it works...

### UPDATE

Use following jQuery code

```
$(".custom-control-input").click(function(){
    var group = "input[name='"+$(this).attr("name")+"']";
    $(group).attr("checked",false);
    $(this).attr("checked",true);
});
```

[Example URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697941/jquery-make-checkboxes-act-like-radio-buttons)

Comment: Could you please give me the full code of this example?

Comment: @HamadEssa I have updated my answer please take a look